# C# LINQ zip function equivalent in query expression

Tags: c#, linq

I can join elements of two lists with the `Zip` function; line1 from file1 with line1 with file2, etc.

`var res = lines1.Zip(lines2, (x, y) => $"{x} {y}");`

Is there a way to do in a query expression?

```
var res = from e1 in lines1
          where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e1)
          from e2 in lines2
          where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e2)
          select $"{e1} {e2}";
```

This joins each line from list1 with each line from list2, which is not what I need.

Comment: why do you want to use the query syntax?

Comment: Similar kind of question is proposed here [Proposal: "with" as a LINQ query expression clause (for Zip())](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/117)

Comment: `.Zip()` like some other methods are not supported in query syntax and you have to switch to method syntax. That's the reason, why I almost always use method syntax, cause it supports the full range (include self-written extension methods), while the query syntax supports a specific subset only.

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal I prefer this syntax.

Comment: @Oliver That's a pity then.

Comment: @JanBodnar not really, this query syntax is less readable, and of course less c#ish

Comment: I think this question can be closed, cause there exists no acceptable answer to make the `.Zip()` operator available through query syntax.

Comment: @Oliver Why don't you create an answer with a short explanation and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the query syntax doesn't support everything that is available through the method syntax (e.g. `Zip()` method, self-written extension methods or 3rd party libraries like MoreLinq).

Due to this limitation it is not possible to get this functionality into C# by the user. Instead Microsoft as owner of the language had to implement such an functionality like it is described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/117).

Answer (score 1):

If you squint pretty hard then this is close:

```
IEnumerable<string> filtered1 =
    from e1 in lines1
    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e1)
    select e1;

IEnumerable<string> filtered2 =
    from e2 in lines2
    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e2)
    select e2;

IEnumerable<string> res =
    from x in filtered1.Zip(filtered2, (e1, e2) => (e1, e2))
    select $"{x.e1} {x.e2}";
```